# Build a Debian package

Tags: package, debian

I'm try to build a Debian package, using this commands :

```
debian/rules clean
dpkg-source -b .
debian/rules build
debian/rules binary
```

I've got this file :

```
myprog_1.1.0.orig.tar.gz
myprog_1.1.0-1.dsc
myprog_1.1.0-1.debian.tar.xz
myprog_1.1.0-1_all.deb
myprog-doc_1.1.0-1_all.deb
```

All the steps have been completed with success. When I open the directory "myprog-1.1.0/debian", I find something which looks like to a Debian package, but my libraries are not in, they are under "myprog-1.1.0/debian/tmp/usr/lib/..."

My questions are : Is it normal ? Is there something else to do to finish this package ? If I'd want it to distribute it, should I recreate a tar.gz from "myprog-1.1.0" ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Debian development and was already answered at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143781/build-a-package-for-debian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I've found a solution. I've added

```
override_dh_auto_install:
     dh_auto_install --destdir=debian/myprog
```

into the file debian/rules.

Hoping that it will help someone someday...

More details on [this discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143781/build-a-package-for-debian)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dpkg-deb --build <derectory> <[deb]>
```

Comment: This may build the package as the asker is looking for. However, you should at least attempt to answer his questions about distribution (which have probably been answered elsewhere).